# flutter firebase (realtime) database with ONE plugin for android,ios,web?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-web

I want to build an app that uses firebase (realtime database) and runs on web AND mobile.
I only found that I need to use two plugins one for web and one for mobile.

So my question is: Is there a way to use firebase (realtime database) on mobile and web more easier (f.e. with only one plugin)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no flutter plugin for realtime database that supports the web, but the flutter team and the community are working on it. When it's done, it should be available here:
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database

Comment: thanks for your answer. so I am going to use this plugin for my project.